# How to know there is a subgroup of order $p^{n(n-1)/2}$ in Aut$\left({\mathbb{Z}\over{p\mathbb{Z}}}\right)^n$ without using Sylow theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose we have the $V=\left({\mathbb{Z}\over{p\mathbb{Z}}}\right)^n$, $p$ is a prime number. Then we can prove the order of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ is $p^{n(n-1)/2}(p^n-1)(p^{n-1}-1)...(p-1)$ ($\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ consists of all the automorphisms in $V$).
To prove this, the basic idea is that we can suppose  $e_{1}=({1,0, \ldots, 0}), e_{2}=(0,1,0, \ldots, 0), \ldots e_{n}=(0,0, \ldots, 1)$. If $u \in \operatorname{Aut}(V)$, then $u(e_{2}) \notin \langle u(e_{1}) \rangle, u(e_{3})\notin \langle u(e_{2}),u(e_{1}) \rangle$ and so on. And the order of $\langle u(e_{1}),u(e_{2})...u(e_{i}) \rangle = p^i$, then the $u(e_{i+1})$ can be $p^n-p^i$ possibilities. Based on this fact, we can finally prove the order of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ is $p^{n(n-1)/2}(p^n-1)(p^{n-1}-1)...(p-1)$.

> Then, how can we prove that there is subgroup whose order is $p^{n(n-1)\over 2}$ in $\operatorname{Aut}(V)$ without using Sylow theorem?

Can someone help me prove it?

Comment: The upper triangular matrices with 1 along the diagonal. Oh yes!@JoelCohen is right - in Aut (V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $N$ for the upper triangular matrices, with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p = \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$, and with $1$ along the diagonal. $N$ is a sub-group of the $\mathop{\rm Aut}(\mathbb F^n_p)$ - closed under multiplication, inversion, and contains the identity matrix - check this!  Above the diagonal, there are $d= (n-1)n/2$ entries (slots) for arbitrary elements of $\mathbb F_p$, so the cardinality of $N$ is $p^d$.

Comment: @user26857: Despite the explicit instructions about comments being only to improve the question/answer, I always feel ambivalent about posting  answer-like comments, such as I made above, as an answer. It was just a hint -  and certainly I am not the only person to place hints in the comments - and the questioner was asking for 'help', not an answer. Would you have placed "hint - <my comment above>" in the answer section? I suppose this is more appropriate for the meta math stack exchange, and is no doubt already there. Best!

Comment: The hints can also be posted as answers (that is, no need to post a full answer if you feel that a hint is enough, or what the OP wants), and the main goal is to remove the question from the unanswered queue. Anyway, +1.